# Get-SPSite pipelining

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to run the following on a very large farm that has over ten thousand site collections:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | Write-Host $_.Url
```

I know that with that many site collections, it would take a long time to list them all, but I was expecting output to at least start showing through the pipeline. Instead it looks like everything is stalled why `Get-SPSite` tries to load everything up into some kind of internal array or list before sending objects down the pipeline.

Is there a way to force the pipelining to happen?

Comment: Can you try this:  Get-SPSite -Limit 100  | select url